# Check for new files in a folder

Tags: php

I have a php script i run every 5 minutes with Cron from a folder. In the folder there is several images and i add more as time goes.

I was wondering how i can make the php script in the beginning check if NEW files exist after the last time the script was run? If new files exist the script should just go on and if no new files exist then it should not go on.  I tried searching around but i cant find anything regarding php.

Anyone that know a quick solution to this problem maybet ?

Answer (score 3):

If the new files are also created with a new timestamp, you can use `filemtime()` to fetch only files that were created/modified in a specified window of time.

Example:

```
$files = glob("folder/*.jpg");
$files = array_filter($files, function ($file) { return filemtime($file) >= time() - 5*60; /* modified in the last 5 minutes */ });

if ($files)
{
   // there are new files! $files is an array with their names
}
```

To make sure you won't miss any file, you might want to store the time from last run somewhere, so in case cron delays a second or two and new files were created precisely within that window, you won't lose track of them.

Update for comments:

Now, to store the time from last check, thats up to you to decide how you will do that, you can use database, file, some sort of environment variable etc., but here is an example of how you can do something really simple storing `time()` in a file:

```
$last  = (int)file_get_contents('folder/timestamp.txt');
file_put_contents('folder/timestamp.txt', time());
$files = glob("folder/*.jpg");
$files = array_filter($files, function ($file) { return filemtime($file) > $last; });

if ($files)
{
   // there are new files! $files is an array with their names
}
```

Just make sure your PHP script can modify `folder/timestamp.txt` and with this script it will always process new files modified since the last run, no matter how long ago it happened.

Comment: Thanks you, how and where would be the best way to store the time and make it check it against that the next time it's run?

Answer (score 0):

**Method :**

1. store current time whenever the cron executed in a file or database.
2. every time when cron starts get the last executed time of the cron from your file or database
3. count the file which creates after last execution time.
4. if count greater than 0. process the cron. other wise stop.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the time the script was last run and use filemtime to check if the file was updated or created after your last execution.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

```
int filemtime ( string $filename )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [**filemtime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)  as follows,You will get the added time as date format.

```
$file_time = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename);
```